# SequelizeJS ordering by nested includes

Tags: sequelize.js

I try to order my include models but it still not working when I add `sub_section` model.

It works for `section` model.

**Working code :**

```
sequelize.models.page
  .findOne({
    where: {
      id
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: sequelize.models.section,
        required: false,
        where: {
          state: true
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: sequelize.models.sub_section,
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    order: [[sequelize.models.section, 'position', 'ASC']]
  })
  .then(findedPage => {
    return findedPage.get({ plain: true });
  });
```

**And not working code with the `sub_section` ordering :**

```
sequelize.models.page
  .findOne({
    where: {
      id
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: sequelize.models.section,
        required: false,
        where: {
          state: true
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: sequelize.models.sub_section
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    order: [[sequelize.models.section, sequelize.models.sub_section, 'position', 'ASC']]
  })
  .then(findedPage => {
    return findedPage.get({ plain: true });
  });
```

I'd like to recieve for each pages all sections ordered and in each section all sub sections ordered.

In the `section` and `sub_section` model I have the `position` property.

Comment: If you indicate included model's fields in the root `order` option then it's pages that will be sorted that way. Try to indicate `order` options in given `include` options